# how to retrieve the image product in the list of sub-product ( select form ) of a bundle product

Tags: image, magento, thumbnails, bundle

Can I retrieve the thumbnail product in the list of sub-product (select form) of a bundle product? How to change the query?

Comment: i found this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16101/
 i will try it

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a bunch of ways to do this, but this one may help:

```
<?php $src = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(125); ?>
<img src='<?php print $src; ?>' />
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to check to make sure that the child item has the 'thumbnail' field loaded. Try:

```
<?php print $_item->getThumbnail(); ?>
```

If you still have no luck, let me know.

Thanks,
Joe